# Grid Challenge HackerRank Edge Case is not working

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am currently practicing my HackerRank and problem-solving skills. I have the following [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/grid-challenge/problem): Given a square grid of characters in the range ascii[a-z], rearrange elements of each row alphabetically, ascending. Determine if the columns are also in ascending alphabetical order, top to bottom. Return YES if they are or NO if they are not.

My solution works for the 11/12 test cases. It is the most efficient way to solve this but it is failing a specific edge case. I would appreciate someone that helps me identify this case and improve the code.

```py
def gridChallenge(grid):
    last_string = ""
    
    for string in grid:
        string = ''.join(sorted(string))
        print(string)
        if string < last_string:
            return "NO"
        last_string = string

    return "YES"
```

Comment: download the problem test case - then go through the 100 cases and isolate where it is failing. I have downloaded the failing one, but it is large and I can't go through all of them for free. If you can't figure out why it is wrong then post that exact case.

Answer (score 3):

#### Where is your code failing?

**Test Case 10 : Grid # 80**

```
2
iv
sm
```

#### Expected Output

**No**, because although `i` is less than `s` but `v` is not less than `m`.

#### Your Output

**Yes**, because, you simply compare `iv` to `sm`; and indeed `iv` is less than `sm`.

#### So what to do?

Compare each column through these strings rather than comparing the entire strings themselves.

#### How do we do that?

- The first step requires sorting each **row** in `grid`, and appending them to another list called `sorted_grid`:

```py
sorted_grid = []
for row in grid:
    sorted_row = sorted(row)
    sorted_grid.append(sorted_row)
```

- Now that we have a `sorted_grid` where each **row** is sorted, we need to check whether each **column** is sorted as well; which is the required task of this problem.
- To do that we unpack the `sorted_grid` using the `*` operator, and pass it to `zip()` function which would create a bunch of columns. We then convert each **column** to a `list` using the `list()` function. A one-liner would like this:

```py
columns = [list(column) for column in zip(*sorted_grid)]
```

- Finally, we iterate over each **column** and each check if it is sorted, by comparing for equality against `sorted(column)`. This check decides whether we must return `"NO"` or `"YES"`. The complete code should look something like this:

```py
def gridChallenge(grid):
    sorted_grid = []
    for row in grid:
        sorted_row = sorted(row)
        sorted_grid.append(sorted_row)
    possible = "YES"
    columns = [list(column) for column in zip(*sorted_grid)]
    for column in columns:
        if column != sorted(column):
            possible = "NO"
            break
    return possible
```

Answer (score 3):

Previous post works just fine and with detail explanations.  Here is just an alternative approach which may help you understand the problem and *improve the code* better.

```py
def gridChallenge(grid):
    sort_grid = [sorted(row) for row in grid]  # List Comp to get sorted rows to start
        
    columns = [list(col) for col in zip(*sort_grid)]  # List Comp. to get cols

    # use generator expression and pass in to all
    if all (col== sorted(col) for col in columns):  # every col is in sorted?
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in JavaScript:

- I created a variable equal to the sorted first row of the grid (ie, previous).
- Then I iterated through the grid, sorting the current row I was on.
- From there I iterated through the current row and checked each element against the same index in the sorted first row variable (previous).
  Example: a against a, c against d, b against e, etc.
- If the previous row variable's element was larger (a will always be smaller than b, b smaller than c, etc) I returned 'NO'
- As the last action of the loop, I then made the previous variable equal to the current sorted row.
- If the current row elements were always larger than the previous row's elements, the function returns "YES"

TLDR: For your code you're just missing the extra step of comparing each element of the row to the previous row's element.

```
  function gridChallenge(grid) {
    let prev = grid[0].split("").sort().join("")
    for (let elem of grid) {
        let newElem = elem.split("").sort().join("");
        for (let i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
            if (prev[i] > newElem[i]) {
                    return "NO"    
            } 
        }
        prev = newElem;
    }
    return "YES"
}
```

```
    gridChallenge([
    "acb",
    "ade",
    "efg"
    ])
```